# Is it allowed for someone to say "I am Muhammad"?

Tags: quran, prophet-muhammad

On an online forum there is someone that keeps saying "I am Muhammad" as if he where impersonating the Prophet himself.

Is this ok? If so/not is there somewhere in the Qur'an that mentions it?

Comment: What if his name is Muhammad?

Comment: Its not. He is saying these things in the context of this "Je suis Charlie" incident, replacing charlie with Muhammad. It just does not seem right to be ranting the name of the Prophet all over the place.

Comment: Everything before Allah is not the actions but the neeyath (intent) behind it.. If the person had an intent to impersonate prophet, then its a haraam / sin. We have no rights to judge nor the knowledge to understand the intent. Only the Almighty can..

Comment: @MohammedAshiq I said the same thing in a different answer.  It is what is in your heart and Allah knows what is in your heart.  What people believe your intentions are is the same as judging another - nobody should judge except Allah.

Comment: @dan yup.. I read that.. That's why I put my opinions in comment.. We don't need two answers conveying the same message. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Is the person is claiming to be the Prophet Mohamed, it is scientifically accurate to say he is lying, since we all know Prophet Mohamed PBUH is dead.

For lying, he is a sinner (liar and hypocrite)  as we all know a sign of hypocrisy is lying.

Answer (score 1):

In Islam it is not allowed for anyone to impersonate any Prophet, be it a Nabi or a Rasool (Messenger).
saying that "I am Muhammad" is not impersonation assuming the gentlemen's name is Muhammad.
You will not find any prohibition in the Quraan directly to the above.

The closest meaning to the name "Muhammad" in English would be "one who is worthy of praise". so the poster could be saying "I am praiseworthy" or he could in fact be named Muhammad.

Answer (score 1):

Well I would agree with the most what has been said in the so far given Answers!

- If somebody says "his Mohammad" and meaning he's the Prophet (May Allah honor him and grant him peace) he's at least lying, maybe a hypocrite.
- if his **intention** is to say by this that he's a Prophet or a Messenger he even would be qualified as a disbeliever. As we know that Mohammad (peace be upon him) is/was the last Prophet from [Qur'an](http://legacy.quran.com/33/40) and Sunna (for example in [Sahih Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/43/164), [Jami' at-Tirmdhi .](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/21/7), and [Sahih al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/64/438)).  and the Prophet (peace be upon him) himself told us that people will come and pretend to be a Messenger of Allah (see for example in [Sahih al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/61/116)).

But on the other hand it's the [**intention**](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/1/1) that matters!
So if he's neither pretending being a Prophet nor a Messenger and he's saying "I'm Mohammad" referring to the Messenger of Allah (May Allah honor him and grant him peace), but not meaning he really is Mohammad in person, then the matter -in my opinion- is according the circumstances and his real intention slightly or even totally different.

In your comment you said he replaced "Charlie" in "Je suis Charlie" by "Mohammad" so he's referring to the "caricature matter" at least in his opinion defending the Messenger of Allah (May Allah honor him and grant him peace). And that's a good cause, intention and deed. But I'm not in the position to judge as I don't know his intention, so maybe it would be regarded as a sin or as a good deed, but initially I would tend to the last one!

Answer (score -1):

As far as I searched, I found nothing related about it. Of course, it could be surveyed from some aspects such as:

Firstly in the case that @Daniel mentioned, if the meaning of the person is "my name is Muhammad", then it doesn't seem to be haram

Secondly in case that the meaning of the mentioned person is that I am prophet Mohammad, then it is completely haram and it is the duty of the related persons in charge (judicial) to arrest him and ...